# MERGE is not merging data as expected

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, merge

My first attempt at a MERGE run is not throughing any errors but it is not merging the data like I want. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? The point is to compair #Temp and #tblCollectionGameList and update #tblCollectionGameList so that it contains only the items inside #Temp (inserting missing items into tblCollecitonGameList and deleteing items from tblColletionGameList that are no longer in #Temp)

```
    CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    CollectionID smallint NOT NULL,
    IncludedSectionID smallint NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Temp (CollectionID, IncludedSectionID) VALUES(0, 0);
INSERT INTO #Temp (CollectionID, IncludedSectionID) VALUES(0, 1);

SELECT * FROM #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #tblCollectionGameList
(
    ID smallint IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    CollectionID smallint NOT NULL,
    IncludedSectionID smallint
)

INSERT INTO #tblCollectionGameList (CollectionID, IncludedSectionID) VALUES(0,0);
INSERT INTO #tblCollectionGameList (CollectionID, INcludedSectionID) VALUES(0,2);

SELECT * FROM #tblCollectionGameList;

BEGIN TRAN

MERGE #tblCollectionGameList AS t
USING #Temp AS s
ON (t.CollectionID = s.CollectionID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT(CollectionID, IncludedSectionID) VALUES (s.CollectionID, s.IncludedSectionID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN
        DELETE;

SELECT * FROM #tblCollectionGameList;

ROLLBACK TRAN

DROP TABLE #Temp;
DROP TABLE #tblCollectionGameList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're joining on a non-unique column.

Everything has `CollectionID = 1` and so everything matches - there are no rows that meet the `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` criteria, and there are no rows that meet the `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` criteria.

Instead try making the `CollectionID` unique within a table.

```
INSERT INTO #Temp (CollectionID, IncludedSectionID) VALUES(0, 0);
INSERT INTO #Temp (CollectionID, IncludedSectionID) VALUES(1, 1);

INSERT INTO #tblCollectionGameList (CollectionID, IncludedSectionID) VALUES(0,0);
INSERT INTO #tblCollectionGameList (CollectionID, INcludedSectionID) VALUES(2,2);
```

Comment: I can't make CollectionID a unique as CollectionID is a FK to another table and one collection can have many SeectionIDs associated to it. Would it work if I upaded the ON statment to add t.IncludedSectionID = s.IncludedSectionID? That would make it fully unique.

Comment: I just tried adding the IncludeSectionID and it looks to work can you just confirm I am thinking right and my test is valid?

Comment: It's valid provided those two columns are the correct key between these tables!